# unicode in web pages in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

my problem in this question is with Persian characters :
in my app , in browser , my messages and texts are display very well but in back of the Scene is not good , look at image:
[image]

and back (in browser page source):
[image]

there are this characters , and main problem is here :

[image]

in view.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var choice in question.QuestionChoices)
                                        {
                                            <div class="databox radius-bordered bg-lightgray">
                                                <div class="databox-right bg-blueberry">
                                                    <div class="databox-piechart">
                                                        <div data-toggle="easypiechart" class="easyPieChart" data-barcolor="#fff" data-linecap="butt" data-percent="50" data-animate="500" data-linewidth="3" data-size="47" data-trackcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" style="width: 47px; height: 47px; line-height: 47px;">
                                                            <span class="white font-90">@choice.AnswerChoices.Count</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="databox-left">
                                                    <span class="databox-number blueberry"><a style="color: inherit">@choice.Text </a></span>
                                                    <div class="databox-text darkgray"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
```

in top code look at : **@choice.Text**
and result:

```
<div class="databox radius-bordered bg-lightgray">
                                                <div class="databox-right bg-blueberry">
                                                    <div class="databox-piechart">
                                                        <div data-toggle="easypiechart" class="easyPieChart" data-barcolor="#fff" data-linecap="butt" data-percent="50" data-animate="500" data-linewidth="3" data-size="47" data-trackcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" style="width: 47px; height: 47px; line-height: 47px;">
                                                            <span class="white font-90">0</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="databox-left">
                                                    <span class="databox-number blueberry"><a style="color: inherit">&#x6AF;&#x632;&#x6CC;&#x646;&#x647; 1 </a></span>
                                                    <div class="databox-text darkgray"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="databox radius-bordered bg-lightgray">
                                                <div class="databox-right bg-blueberry">
                                                    <div class="databox-piechart">
                                                        <div data-toggle="easypiechart" class="easyPieChart" data-barcolor="#fff" data-linecap="butt" data-percent="50" data-animate="500" data-linewidth="3" data-size="47" data-trackcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" style="width: 47px; height: 47px; line-height: 47px;">
                                                            <span class="white font-90">1</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="databox-left">
                                                    <span class="databox-number blueberry"><a style="color: inherit">&#x6AF;&#x632;&#x6CC;&#x646;&#x647;2 </a></span>
                                                    <div class="databox-text darkgray"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

now in top html rendered a **(گزینه 2)** as a code
how i can fix this issue?

my code is in C# and Asp.net Core.
tnx.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking... So far you've highlighted valid looking HTML (6xx are plausible to be Persian characters)... Could you please [edit] post and show HTML as text (instead of images) and more importantly what you expecting to see (presumably instead of valid HTML shown in the post currently).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hi, edited

Comment: .NET strings *are* Unicode. The page you read is a Unicode page generated by ASP.NET *without any kind of special handling or encoding*. You could type Chinese or Arabic characters without any problem. Where does the text come from? It seems like it was encoded in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(
            HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
                UnicodeRanges.Arabic }));
```

Comment: Or *avoid* HTML encoding completely. .NET strings *are* Unicode. This page you read is Unicode. You could type Arabic or Chinese text in a question or comment and have it displayed without any kind of encoding

Comment: In fact, I see your question contains Arabic already, so you've proved yourself that HtmlEncoder is *not* needed. You should *remove* any encoding attempt in your action code (which is missing from the question)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a component called "easypiechart" which is not displaying the characters correctly. Is that right?

You must talk to the easypiechart programmers and find a way to fix the problem.

The problem does not seem to be with asp.net core.